# Text flowing out of Div

Tags: css

I have two columns, A and B.  When I add text (about 4-5 complete sentences) to column A, it just scrolls across the screen into column B.

What can I do to prevent this?  Essentially, I just want the text in column A to "word wrap" in the space provided.  I also want to avoid any scroll bars.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Set a width on column A so that it doesn't default to 100%

Comment: The width for both columns were defined.